# Get more than 200 group members from the Meetup API

Tags: javascript, meetup

Using the Meetup API, I'm able to successfully get exactly 200 members from any given group. There are a lot of groups that have more members than that. I want to know how to get them all.

**The issue**
I haven't been able to find where `&page=###` is documented. I'm assuming it sets how many results are returned in the response from Meetup.

I have tried using, for example, `&page=1000`, but I still only get 200 members back.

**The request URL**
I'm using this URL to request the data:

```
let meetupReqUrl = "https://api.meetup.com/2/members?&sign=true&group_id=" 
                  + groupId 
                  + "&key=" 
                  + apiKeys.meetup
                  + "&order=joined"
                  + "&page=1000"
```

This variation also returns exactly 200 members:

```
let meetupReqUrl = "https://api.meetup.com/2/members?&sign=true&group_id=" 
                  + groupId 
                  + "&order=joined"
                  + "&page=1000" 
                  + "&key=" 
                  + apiKeys.meetup
```

It may be worth noting that `&order=joined` is not sorting the results at all. This leads me to believe I am doing something wrong in forming the URL.

**Related documentation**
Meetup's `/2/members` API is [documented here](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/2/members/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the maximum number of results you can get **at once** through the API is 200 - see https://github.com/jkutianski/meetup-api/wiki#limits.

You can however make multiple requests as per http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/#making_request. It says you need to use the page and offset parameters. From the meetup.com link:

*page -- the page size (maximum number of results in each response) to use on the results*

*offset -- the starting page for results to return. For example, when page = 10, specifying "offset=0" will bring back records 1-10, "offset=1" will bring records 11-20, etc.*

Comment: It is necessary to include both the `page` and `offset` parameter. `Offset` will not return any results if the `page` arg isn't included.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm answering again because I don't have enough reputation to edit my previous answer, since it was turned into a comment).

The way `offset` and `page` work is not so intuitive. They actually are dependent on and multiply each other. For example, if `page` is set to 20 and `offset` is 2, you will skip 40 entries down. I figured this out using the [API console](https://secure.meetup.com/meetup_api/console/?path=/find/groups) because I couldn't find any documentation that specified their relationship.

This also explains why offset does not work on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware though, offset does not work if order is set to time. `order=time`.
Also, if you order the response by time, it will reduce the amount of returned results (around 80%), so if you set your `page=20` you will receive around 16 results.